# Sort values of a dataframe column based on positive and negative values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df column consisting of +ve and -ve columns.

```
       A          B
0      a           5
1      b         -13
2      c          15
3      d         -10
```

And is there a way to sort out +ve values ascending and -ve values descending

```
       A          B
0      a           5
1      c          15
2      d         -10
3      b         -13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First filter both with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
mask = df['B'].gt(0)
df = pd.concat([df[mask].sort_values('B'),
                df[~mask].sort_values('B', ascending=False)], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   A   B
0  a   5
1  c  15
2  d -10
3  b -13
```